# Slicing in group by function

Tags: pandas

How do I group by data frame based on first column after splitting data on semi colon?
In this example I need to split on last column time and group by hour.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myst="""india, 905034 , 19:44   
USA, 905094  , 19:33
Russia,  905154 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols=['country', 'index', 'current_tm']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

This query does not return the expected results:

```
df[df['index'] > 900000].groupby([df.current_tm]).size()

current_tm
   21:56     1
 19:33       1
 19:44       1
dtype: int64
```

It should be :

```
21 1
19 2
```

The time is in hh:mm format but pandas consider it as string.

Is there any utility that will convert the SQL query to pandas equivalent? (something like querymongo.com that will help mongoDB users)

Comment: Your df is malformed you have embedded spaces in your 'current_tm' column: `In [109]:

current_tm
df['current_tm'].tolist()
Out[109]:
[' 19:44   ', ' 19:33', '   21:56']` You need to fix this and then you can start thinking about getting the hour component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the hour to your dataframe as follows and then use it for grouping:

```
df['hour'] = df.current_tm.str.strip().apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[0] if isinstance(x, str) 
                                                       else None)

>>> df[df['index'] > 900000].groupby('hour').size()
hour
19      2
21      1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column:

```
df['hour'] = [current_time.split(':')[0] for current_time in df['current_tm']]
```

Then apply your method:

```
df[df['index'] > 900000].groupby([df['hour']]).size()

hour
19    2
21    1
dtype: int64
```